# What are the empty files after RDD.saveAsTextFile?

Tags: java, apache-spark, data-analysis, apache-spark-1.3

I'm learning Spark by working through some of the examples in Learning Spark: Lightning Fast Data Analysis and then adding my own developments in.

I created this class to get a look at basic transformations and actions.

```
/**
 * Find errors in a log file
 */

package com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini.java;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

public class FindErrors {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String inputFile = args[0];
        String outputFile = args[1];
        //Create a Spark context
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("findErrors");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        //Load input data
        JavaRDD<String> input = sc.textFile(inputFile);
        //Split up into words
        JavaRDD<String> errorsRDD = input.filter(
            new Function<String, Boolean>() {
                public Boolean call(String x) {
                    return x.contains("error");
                }
            });
        //Transform into word and count
        //errorsRDD.saveAsTextFile(outputFile);

        JavaRDD<String> warningsRDD = input.filter(
            new Function<String, Boolean>() {
                public Boolean call(String x) {
                    return x.contains("warning");
                }
            });

        JavaRDD<String> badLinesRDD = errorsRDD.union(warningsRDD);

        badLinesRDD.saveAsTextFile(outputFile);

        System.out.println("I had " + badLinesRDD.count() + " concerning lines.");
        System.out.println("Here are 10 examples:");
        for(String line: badLinesRDD.take(10)){
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    }   
}
```

Here's the command I used to run it:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.mini.java.FindErrors ./target/learning-spark-mini-example-0.0.1.jar ../files/fake_logs/log1.log ./errorLog
```

Here's the contents of the log file:

```
66.249.69.97 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:25:44 +0000] "GET /071300/242153 HTTP/1.1" 404 514 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
71.19.157.174 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
71.19.157.174 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1713 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
71.19.157.174 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18785 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
71.19.157.174 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:37 +0000] "GET /jobmineimg.php?q=m HTTP/1.1" 200 222 "http://www.holdenkarau.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
71.19.157.175 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
71.19.157.175 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
71.19.157.174 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:37 +0000] "GET /jobmineimg.php?q=m HTTP/1.1" 200 222 "http://www.holdenkarau.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
71.19.157.175 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000] "GET /warning HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
71.19.157.175 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000] "GET /warning HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
```

One thing I noticed is that the output creates several files rather than the one file I expected.

The files are:

```
_SUCCESS


part-00000
71.19.157.174 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
71.19.157.175 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"

part-00001
71.19.157.175 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"

part-00002


part-00003
71.19.157.175 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000] "GET /warning HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
71.19.157.175 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000] "GET /warning HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
```

It appears as if a file is created for each "grouping" of warnings/errors. What is the blank file for though?

Also, is this likely to be something that's in my code which I haven't found yet or is it a feqature of Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature. With `saveAsTextFile` Spark writes a single output file per partition, no matter if it contains data or not. Since you apply `filter` some input partitions, which originally contained data, can end up empty. Hence the empty files.

Comment: Cheers user6910411.